# How to use a downloaded Bitbucket Reporsitory in Pycharm

Tags: frameworks, pycharm, repository, bitbucket, bdd

I have a repository that is in BitBucket here are the two things I want to do. 
1. Download the repository and use it in Pycharm. 
2. Directly connect to the repository in Bitbucket.

I have a testing framework that is in the repository but I can't figure how can I use that framework in Pycharm to write my test cases.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any error messages occuring? Try to be as specific as possible to help others help you.

Comment: @phifi I have tried VCS in Pycharm - Get from Version control and added the URL of the repository but I get a message  `Clone Failed Unable to access Https://: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` I have also tried this command  `git clone ssh://git@`. I have both read and write permission to the repository.